# Adding to a specific variable in a list

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm trying to add two lists. If the last variable is greater than 10, it needs to carry over to the previous variable in the list. For example :

```
1 / 2 / 3 (List 1)
7 / 8 / 9 (List 2)
```

Should equal

```
9 / 1 / 2 not 8/10/12
```

So far, I have

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]    
list2 = [7, 8, 9]    
SumOfLists = [x+y for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

That adds the lists together, but I'm not sure how to make the number carry over.

Comment: In SumOfLists, it adds the lists together. The if statement is my attempt at trying to carry over the number.

Comment: Please do check if my answer has correctly answered your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```python
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [7, 8, 9]

def add_list(a,b):
    carry = 0
    res_list = []
    for i,j in zip(a[::-1],b[::-1]):   # Iterate through the lists in reverse
        val = (i+j+carry)%10           # Store the sum in val
        carry = (i+j+carry)//10        # Store the carry
        res_list.append(val)           # Append to the returning list
    return res_list[::-1]              # Return the list

print add_list(list1,list2)
```

Wil print

```
[9, 1, 2]
```

Algorithm

Loop through each of the values in reverse. Add each corresponding values. If the values are above 10 then find the exceeding value and put it to carry. Finally return the reverse of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [7, 8, 9]
cur = 0    # num to carry over
result = []
for x,y in zip(reversed(list2),reversed(list1)):
    if x + y + cur > 10: # if sum greater than 10, remember to add 1 on 
        t = x+y + cur    # the next loop
        d = str(t)[1]    # get the rightmost digit
        result.append(int(d))
        cur = 1
    else:                # nothing to curry over, but still add cur,
                         # it may be 1 
        result.append(x+y+cur)
        cur = 0

print(list(reversed(result)) )

[9, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

just subtract 10 if it's more then 10 and add 1 to it's previous element. Do this proccess for all element in sum list

```
if SumOfLists[2] >= 10:
    SumOfLists[2] -= 10 
    SumOfLists[1] += 1
```

And at last check

```
if SumOfLists[0] >= 10:
    for i in range(len(SumOfLists)-1,0,-1):
        SumOfLists[i] = SumOfLists[i-1]
    SumOfLists[0] = 1
```

Comment: What if `SumOfLists[0]` is greater than ten?

Comment: Den just add 1 to list starting element and shift all element left.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that?

Comment: Added in my solution how to shift all element and add 1 to starting.

Comment: I tried running your code with inputs `list1 = [3, 2, 3]; list2 = [7, 8, 9]` and got `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: Extremely very very sorry i forgot to subtract 1 please check it now. I update solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92308/discussion-between-kapil-rupavatiya-and-kevin).